# Evaluating a Gaussian integral on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: calculus, gamma-function, spherical-coordinates, gaussian-integral

For $t>0$ I want to show that $$\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{\frac{-\|x\|^{2}}{4t}}dx=1$$

So far, I have

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{\frac{-\|x\|^{2}}{4t}}dx&=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{n-1}e^{-\frac{r^{2}}{4t}}drd\theta
\\
&=\frac{\omega_{n-1}}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{n-1}e^{-\frac{r^{2}}{4t}}dr
\\
&=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{n-1}e^{-\frac{r^{2}}{4t}}dr
\end{aligned}$$

But from here I have not been able to proceed, although I realise that the integral looks something like the integral function.

Although the Wikipedia article on Gaussian integrals shows computations on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ I could not find resources on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you do
$$\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\|x^2||/(4t)} \mathop{dx} = \prod_{j=1}^n\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x_j^2/(4t)}\mathop{dx_j}\right]=1?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of $t$ through a suitable substitution then apply [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), without switching to polar coordinates:
$$ \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\,dx\,\,dy\,dz = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}\,du\right)^3,$$
for instance.